# parsing csv file that has newline characters in one of columns in AWS Athena/ AWS Glue catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I've sample data like below:

```
id,log,code,sequence
100,sample <(>&<)> O sample ? PILE UP - 3 sample,20,7^M$
101,sample- 4/52$
sample$
CM,21,7^M$
102,sample AT 3PM,22,4^M$
```

In second row (id=101), log column has newline characters making 3 lines out of one line.
I've enabled ":set list" option in vim editor to show newline ($) and endofline (^M) characters.

To handle newline characters [AWS Suggested OpenCSVSerde here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html). 
I tried using OPENCSVSerde serialisation with `escapeChar=\\, quoteChar=\", seperatorChar=`,
Nonetheless, it is showing data as 5 rows where as I need three rows.
When I query in Athena, id=101 is showing only first line and rest is missing:

```
id,log,code,sequence
101,sample- 4/52
```

Any tips or example on how to handle multiline characters in a csv file column?

I'm exploring custom classifiers but no luck yet.

Answer (score 2):

According to this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html opencsvserde does not support line breaks.

I see that you are trying to put some kind of log there.
Your options are:

- Cleanup the log not to include the line breaks. Or,
- use regexserde, which is not useful if your log format keeps changing. Or,
- If both are not an option you can change ur format from csv to parquet or something else, where there are no line break issues

Comment: Hi Nelson, can you elaborate on parquet option?

Comment: Parquet does not take new line chars into consideration. So you'll not see multiple columns like this if u r using parquet. It'll just ignore them.

Comment: I don't think the regex serde supports multiline records either, unfortunately.