# AWS Athena returning empty rows on table creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create a table in AWS Athena query editor using this statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS somedb.sometable (
  meta string, 
  content string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'input.regex' = "\"([^\\n]*)\\n([^>]*)\"g"
)
LOCATION 's3://some-location/';
```

The file I'm trying to process looks something like this:

```
>some metadata
content line
content line
content line
content line
>some more metadata
content line
content line
more content lines
```

The goal is to create a table with two columns, one being metadata, the other one being multiline content described below the metadata. The regex that is tested [using regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rsO4OD/4), and seems to work properly.

The problem is that querying the data returns empty rows. Executing `SELECT count(*) FROM "somedb"."sometable"` returns the same number as there are lines in the file that is being processed. In my case file has 63000 lines and the count query returns 63000. Each row contains no data in it.

Also tried to create a table using the Athena table wizard, getting the same result.

Comment: I tried your code using `'input.regex' = "([^\\n]*)\\n([^>]*)"` but also got blank rows. It is possible that `RegexSerDe` does not support multi-line input, but I couldn't find a definitive answer in my searches.

Comment: I had similar issue with csv file and handled it through custom classifier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036894/parsing-csv-file-that-has-newline-characters-in-one-of-columns-in-aws-athena-aw